# Trouble reading analog (PWM)

Tags: pwm, digital-analog-conversion

I'm trying to test my `analog` signal before I send it to an actual `analog` device. I've written some code and considering the `analog` square I have expected to see a `digital` **ON** *or* **OFF** during a single `duty cycle` but I'm either seeing all **OFF** for `analog` values 0-127 and all **ON** for values 128-255.

My expectation is that I would see 51 **ON** and 49 **OFF** thus getting a value closer to 128 of 255.

**What am I missing? Is this even possible?**

```
int OUTPUT_PIN = 2; // digital 2 (PWM)
int INPUT_PIN = A0; // analog 0

void setup() {
  pinMode(OUTPUT_PIN, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(INPUT_PIN, INPUT);

  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {

  analogWrite(OUTPUT_PIN, 128);

  float j = 0;
  for(int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) { // get 100 reads per duty cycle
    float v;
    v = digitalRead( INPUT_PIN );
    if(v >= 1) Serial.println("ON");
    if(v <= 0) Serial.println("OFF");
    j += v;

    delay(12); // trying to match the duty cycle
  }
  j /= 100; // average out the 100 reads

  Serial.println(j);

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seeing all on for 128+ and all off for 127- is indicative that you are using a pin that can't do PWM.

If you use a non-PWM pin with analogWrite it goes "Is this less than 128? Yes? Then I will turn it off. Otherwise I will turn it on.".

```
case NOT_ON_TIMER:
default:
    if (val < 128) {
        digitalWrite(pin, LOW);
    } else {
        digitalWrite(pin, HIGH);
    }
```

Since you don't mention what board you are using I can only assume that you have picked a pin that can't do PWM. Change to a pin that *can* do PWM and you should get a PWM signal.

Comment: I tried on both Mega 2560 and Uno. I see now on the uno that some digital pins have a `~` in front of the number. Coincidentally these are the only pins which send a PWM signal. Moving from outpin pin `2` to `3` solved the issue.

Comment: That's not coincidental. The `~` is used to denote which pins can do PWM. Like it says on the board: `DIGITAL (PWM ~)`

Comment: You are completely right. You've certainly made me very aware of my rookie mistake. Thanks for your time in helping me track down my issue.